# Regular Expression for replace all non digit expect symbols

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, multilingual

i can't figure out this thing i think it possible with only one pattern, please help me improve.

I have this string `2 / 3 items` and i wont receive only `2 / 3`

Items can also be write in cirillic so `2 / 3 штуки`

So i think the best way is use `\D` all non digit (result `23`)

But this delete also the slash that i want to keep, how i can do?

```php
// this was my solution for now, 
// but it not complete for cirillic cause i have an error
// it return: 2 / 3 �
// maybe is something with encoding?
preg_replace('@[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]*@', '', '2 / 3 штуки');

// so i chose to do this, but doesn't know how to keep slash
preg_replace('@[\D]*@', '', '2 / 3 штуки');
// it return: 23


# How to get 2 / 3 ?
```

Comment: You can exclude the slash `[^\d/]+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird nice, it work! But correct way is this `[^\d\/]+` and also for whitespaces `[^\d\s\/]+`

Comment: You use `@` as a delimiter, so you don't have to escape the forward slash.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank u very much, i doens't know this

Comment: Артур, it is much safer to extract what you need rather than replace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Spasibo! Yes i figure this out now

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
if (preg_match('~\d+\s*/\s*\d+~u', $text, $match)) {
  echo $match[0];
}
```

Also, if the fraction part is optional, use

```php
preg_match('~\d+(?:\s*/\s*\d+)?~u', $text, $match)
```

And if you need to extract all occurrences, use `preg_match_all`:

```php
preg_match_all('~\d+(?:\s*/\s*\d+)?~u', $text, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBVBKq/1) and the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/oWF3E). Note that `preg_match` *extracts* the match rather than remove it (as is the case with `preg_replace`).

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `\s*/\s*` - `/` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits

Note that `u` is used in case the whitespace in your string can be other than regular ASCII whitespace, like `\xA0`.